# How To Query For An Empty Taxonomy Field

Tags: taxonomy, tax-query

I want to write a query that looks up taxonomies.  One condition is that taxonomyA returns x, and a second condition is that taxonomyB returns empty.  I don't know how to query for empty.

This is what I have:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'areaoflondon',
            'field'            => 'name',
            'terms'            => 'South London',
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'yearofvisit',
            'field'            => 'name',
            'terms'            => '',
            'include_children' => false,
          ]
    ],
    'posts_per_page'     => 5,
    'meta_key' => 'rating',
    'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
];
```

However this doesn't return any results.

How can I query that a taxonomy is empty?  Is it even possible?

Thanks
James

Comment: Have you tried using the EXISTS operator? E.g. `[ 'taxonomy' => 'yearofvisit', 'operator' => 'EXISTS' ]`

Comment: Or maybe try the `NOT EXISTS` operator, depending on what the "empty taxonomy" means in your code/context.

Comment: That is perfect - much appreciated.

Comment: , but please post an answer and show the code that worked for you. (And accept your answer so that it's clear to others that this question has an accepted solution)

Comment: Thanks...assumed you'd want the honour but have done so :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sally for the answer, which is to use the NOT EXISTS operator:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'areaoflondon',
            'field'            => 'name',
            'terms'            => 'South London',
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'yearofvisit',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
          ]
    ],
    'posts_per_page'     => 5,
    'meta_key' => 'rating',
    'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
];
```